# Grabbing freetext and radio button values in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have several radio buttons, and the last radio button has a freetext option next to it. I had success getting the values of the radio button OR the freetext, but never both in the same function.

If I had 3 choices, and the 4th choice was another, I would want the function to grab the value without creating a separate Javascript function.

Here was my attempt:

```html
<input type="radio" id = "choice1" name="snooze" value="samplechoice0" onClick='valuechanged();'/> samplechoice0<br>
<input type="radio" id = "choice2" name="snooze" value="samplechoice1" onClick='valuechanged();'/> samplechoice1<br>
<input type="radio" id = "choice3" name="snooze" value="samplechoice2" onClick='valuechanged();'/> samplechoice2 <br>
<input type="radio" id = "choice10" name="snooze" value="Normal Radio"  onClick='valuechanged();'/>
<input type="text"  id = "choice11" class="tb" name="tb1"  placeholder="Enter Other Reason Here" onkeypress='valuechanged();' > <br>
```

```js
function Submit() {
    var items=document.getElementsByClassName('radio');
    var selectedItems=" ";

    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].type=='radio' && items[i].checked==true && document.getElementById('choice10').checked==false) {
            selectedItems+=items[i].value+"; ";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("choice10").checked == true) {
        selectedItems = document.getElementById('choice11').value;
         
    }
    alert(selectedItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, I would pair the two together using a name that matches the radio input's value. For example, if you have a radio input with `value="other"`, just create a textbox with `name="otherText"`

Then, using an object like `{ snooze, snoozeText }`, allow both values to potentially be `undefined`, empty string, or whatever else works in your situation. For example:

```js
document.querySelector('.js-snooze-form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formElements = e.currentTarget.elements
  
  // Get the snooze value
  const snoozeEl = Array.from(formElements.snooze).filter(el => el.checked)[0]
  const snooze = snoozeEl && snoozeEl.value
  
  // Get the paired text, if any
  const snoozeTextEl = formElements[`${snooze}Text`]
  const snoozeText = snoozeTextEl && snoozeTextEl.value
  
  // "Return" the checked snooze value paired with the reason text
  console.log({ snooze, snoozeText })
})
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-items: start;
}
```

```html
<form class="js-snooze-form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="snooze" value="0" />Choice 0</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="snooze" value="1" />Choice 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="snooze" value="2" />Choice 2</label>

  <!-- Define a pairing between other & otherText -->
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="snooze" value="other" />Other:</label>
    <input name="otherText" placeholder="Enter Other Reason Here" />
  </div>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ID of the last radio button with free text dynamically by making it equal to the text which is given in by the user.
I also added in following code that when the user gives text input next to the last radio button, the last radio button is automatically checked.
You can then grab the ID of the radio button which is checked.

```
<form id="radiobuttonForm" name="radiobuttonForm">
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1"> samplechoice0
<br>        
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2"> samplechoice1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3"> samplechoice2
<br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="other" class="other_reason_radio"> samplechoice3 
input type="text" id="other_reason_text_input"/>
</form>
```

```
var choice;
function getChoice(){
    var radios = document.forms["radiobuttonForm"].elements["choice"];
    for(var i = 0, max = radios.length-1; i < max; i++) {
        radios[i].onclick = function() {
            choice=this.id;
            console.log('choice: ', choice);
        }
    }
    radios[radios.length-1].onclick = function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("other_reason_radio")[0].id=document.getElementById("other_reason_text_input").value;
            choice=this.id;
            console.log('choice: ', choice);
    }   
}

document.getElementById("radiobuttonForm").addEventListener("click", getChoice());

document.getElementById('other_reason_text_input').addEventListener('input', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("other_reason_radio")[0].checked = true;
    document.getElementsByClassName("other_reason_radio")[0].id=document.getElementById("other_reason_text_input").value;
    choice=document.getElementById("other_reason_text_input").value;
    console.log('choice: ', choice);
});
```